# Google Maps geocoding service Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

I want to loop through an array of addresses and retrieve the lat-lng coordinates from Google geocoding before the page loads so I can have markers on all the addresses. When I attempt to do that though I get the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

Everyone suggests to use the geocoding API but I don't need anything dynamic. I already have the information I need when the webpage loads up.

```
var url = 
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=true";

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.send();
```

As you can see, the code is simple enough, but is there a way to get around the error while still using the http request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Origin url is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Google Direction API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807052/origin-url-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-with-google-direction-a)

Answer (score 1):

Just today I faced the same error as yours, and the solution is in this other question on SO

[Origin url is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Google Direction API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807052/origin-url-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-with-google-direction-a)

As I saw, you now have to use the Geocoding API to search addresses, even if you have the specific address.

Hope this helps

Comment: You could flag it as a duplicate, or add it as a comment. Are you sure this qualifies as an answer?

Comment: I don't see any option for me to flag it as duplicate... so I posted a link to help. I don't know if it qualifies as an answer, everything on SO needs to be perfect. I just wanted to help, because I came from google to this exact question.

Comment: No problem. Just asking :)