# Conditional AngularJS $httpProvider interceptor? Google maps rejecting requests due to conflict with Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am building a MEAN stack application, and for authentication/authorization I basically followed the recommendations of scotch.io's MEAN Machine book. So, I am using JWTs and attaching them to every request from the client via http interceptor. However, one of the features of the application is a google map that plots various points relevant to the user, and I'm running a function in the map controller that geocodes city/state values from a list and drops them on the map.

This had been working fine until yesterday, when I began to see the following error in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=READING,+PA&key=<API_KEY>. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I set up the interceptor in my app.config:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
```

I was initially using the request header `x-access-token` as used in the book, but was getting the same error. I changed to `Authorization`, thinking that it might be more commonly accepted. But that didn't work. So I thought the best approach might be to conditionally add the request header to any request that's not going to maps.googleapis.com:

```
app.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$q', 'AuthToken', function($q, AuthToken) {

  var interceptorFactory = {};

  // attach the token to every HTTP request
  interceptorFactory.request = function(config) { 

    // have tried a couple conditional statements to avoid 
    // attaching the Authorization header to google maps requests:
    // if (config.url.substr(8, 19) !== 'maps.googleapis.com') {

    if (!_.startsWith(config.url, 'https://maps.googleapis.com') {
      // grab the token
      var token = AuthToken.getToken();
      // if the token exists, add it to the header as Authorization
      if (token) { 
        config.headers['Authorization'] = token;
      }
    }
    return config; 
  };
  ...
  return interceptorFactory; 
}]);
```

But neither of the conditional statements has worked. Am I thinking about this the right way? Am I correct in assuming that this is the source of the error, and that it should be possible to leave the `Authorization` header off of the request if the request meets certain criteria, or is that not the way that AngularJS interceptors work?

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thanks.

UPDATE: I neglected to include the second parenthesis after the `if (!_.startsWith(config.url, 'https://maps.googleapis.com')`. It's working as expected now.

Comment: You might consider using the client-side library instead? [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807052/origin-url-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-with-google-direction-a)

Comment: Also, have you inspected the requests being made by your application or stepped through your code in a debugger to see if the conditionals aren't working?

Comment: Oy, was missing the parenthesis after the `if (!_.startsWith(config.url, 'https://maps.googleapis.com')`. Well, it's working now. /slaps forehead/ Thanks for taking a look.